# How can I "deeply" clone the properties of closed source 3rd party classes?

Tags: c#, .net, class, object, clone

The [ICloneable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.100).aspx) interface of the .NET framework usually provides a way to support [cloning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloning_%28programming%29) of an instance of a class.

But if I have **multiple 3rd party classes**, and don't want to care about each of the properties individually, how can I clone objects of those classes efficiently? (The source code of those classes is not available).
Is there a way using [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

What I need is a deep clone which creates an exact copy including all the properties and (child) objects.

---

**Example:** Suppose you want to clone a `UserQuery` object in [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/):

```
void Main()
{
    UserQuery uc=this;
    var copy=uc.CreateCopy(); // clone it
}
```

What I am looking for is a `CreateCopy()` extension that allows to create a copy without having to take care of the details of this class since I don't own the source of `UerQuery`.

(Note that `UserQuery` is just an example to show what I require, it could as well be a PDF document class, a user control class, a ADO.NET class or anything else).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have currently **2 different solutions** for this, one with and one without the use of reflection:

---

**1.)** With a **generic extension method** (plus **[reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183(v=vs.100).aspx)**) you can do it this way in C#:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static T CreateCopy<T>(this T src)
        where T: new()
    {
        if (src == null) return default(T); // just return null
        T tgt = new T(); // create new instance
        // then copy all properties
        foreach (var pS in src.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            foreach (var pT in tgt.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (pT.Name != pS.Name) continue;
                (pT.GetSetMethod()).Invoke(tgt, new object[] { 
                    pS.GetGetMethod().Invoke(src, null) });
            }
        };
        return tgt;
    } // method
} // class
```

This is very powerful, because now you can **clone every object,** not just objects from the classes you have written, but from all classes **including the system classes** of the .NET Framework. And thanks to reflection, **you don't need to know its properties,** they are copied automatically.

### Example

To use the method `CreateCopy()`, let's say you have a `Customer` class and a `Order` class, and you need to create copies (not references) but with new IDs. Then you can do the following:

```
Order CopyOrderWithNewPK(Order item)
{
    Order newItem = item.CreateCopy(); // use ext. method to copy properties
    newItem.OrderId = new Guid(); // create new primary key for the item
    return newItem;
}
```

Not surprisingly, for the Customer class it would look the same:

```
Customer CopyCustomerWithNewPK(Customer item)
{
    Customer newItem = item.CreateCopy(); // use ext. method to copy properties
    newItem.CustomerId = new Guid(); // create new primary key for the item
    return newItem;
}
```

**Note** that the values of all properties defined within the example classes are copied automatically. You can even clone an object of a 3rd party assembly if you don't own the source code. The trade-off is, that the reflection approach is slower.

---

**2.)** There's another another way to do it **without reflection**, inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11599526/1016343) question. One advantage is that it even is able to clone the objects of the Entity Framework (for example to attach and re-attach entity objects to a different data context):

```
// using System.Runtime.Serialization;
public class Cloner<T>
{
    readonly DataContractSerializer _serializer 
            = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));

    /// <summary>
    /// Clone an object graph
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="graph"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public T Clone(T graph)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        _serializer.WriteObject(stream, graph);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return (T)_serializer.ReadObject(stream);
    }
}
```

In order to not break the examples above, you can change the extension method `CreateCopy` as follows:

```
public static class Extension
{   
    public static T CreateCopy<T>(this T src)
        where T: new()
    {
            return (new Cloner<T>()).Clone(src);
    }   
}
```

**Note:** Although `Cloner` is using `System.Runtime.Serialization`, the object being cloned does **not** need to be serializable. This can be an advantage, other solutions I have seen can only clone serializable objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you implement the `ICloneable` you dont have to care about each property! Your answer is good but for me its pretty much code and reflections have low performance (!), i prefer to use

```
class Test : ICloneable
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }

    #region ICloneable-Member

    public object Clone()
    {
        return base.MemberwiseClone();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: +1 for the straight-forward approach. You are right, reflection is slower. In my case, I had to clone an object of a 3rd party assembly where I didn't own the source code. So the only way to do this was the approach with an extension method and generics.